# Not performing yes click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So what's supposed to happen is when the user clicks the yes answer its supposed to get the id of the img and then perform its tasks but I don't know if I should be putting the id onto the link instead of the image but the main part of the question is its not doing the steps of the yes click function.

I was using the same plugin from this page. http://webstuffshare.com/demo/jConfirmAction/index.html 
And using the plugin with the default usage

```
<td> 
<a class="ask" href="#"> 
<img id="2" class="delete" border="0" title="" alt="" src="images/trash.png"> 
 </a>
 <div class="question" style="opacity: 1;">
  Are You Sure ?
   <br>
  <span class="yes">Yes</span>
  <span class="cancel">Cancel</span>
 </div>
</td>

$('.ask').jConfirmAction();

$('.yes').bind('click', function(){
    var userID = $(this).parent.attr('id'); 
    var dataString = 'userID=' + userID + '&deleteuser=True'; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "processes/template.php", 
        data: dataString, 
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").eq(0).hide();   
});
```

Comment: Note that this was edited to show the generated mark-up from the plugin. The original use case did not have those spans.

Comment: Okay, so what is the scenario here? Are you trying to create a confirmation prompt for deleting a user?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have anything with a class of `yes` to bind that click to.

EDIT: (post addition of generated code)

try putting your id in your `<div class="question" style="opacity: 1;">` if you can't do add it to your td and change to `var userID = $(this).parents('td').attr('id')`;

Comment: I'd thought that this was only a partial script, but this still seems very likely. +1.

Comment: Well what happens with the jquery plugin is that when you click on the object that has a class of ask it brings up the little toolbox that handles the confirm action of either yes or no. That part is written into the jsConfrimAction function.

Comment: @Jeff, can you then please post the html of the generated toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what you should be seeing in the client (the web browser) is this:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="ask">
        <img src="images/trash.png" class="delete" alt="" title="" border="0" id="some value" />
    </a>
</td>
```

So, you gave your **image** an id, yet your jQuery selector is an attempt to bind a click event to the **hyperlink**, with a function that tries to parse the id of the **table cell**. As someone else mentioned, the selector selects nothing because there is nothing that matches it.

Do you see where I'm going with this?

**Edit:**

To set the click event on the image:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){ 
    var id = e.target.id; 

    // ... the rest here
});
```

To set it on the hyperlink:

```
$(".ask").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).("img").attr("id"); 

    // ... the rest here
});
```

**Edit 2:**

If your goal is to provide a confirmation prompt, I'd follow the K.I.S.S. principle; use the JavaScript confirmation prompt when the delete link is clicked:

```
$(".ask").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
        var id = $(this).("img").attr("id"); 

        // ... the rest here
    }
});
```

Comment: Using the classes you provided? `$(".delete").click(function(e){ var id = e.target.id; });` should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: does that go inside of the yes bind event?

Comment: but your missing out on the yes class

Comment: I updated the code so you can understand what the generated code looks like.

Comment: Now its' not even bringing up the toolbox. when I click the image with class of delete

Comment: Well, there was a closing bracket missing, if you copied it verbatim. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `alert("Some message");` just before your call to the bind. Place another as the first instruction of your `function()`. to see if both of these pieces of code are even being reached.